# I'm having a repeating try block issue

Tags: python, file, io, block, repeat

So i'm making a little app here, and I have try blocks (because I need to see if a file already exists or should be created). Although... my try block is repeating for some reason! I have **ABSOLUTELY** *no idea* why this is happening. Please help?
Also, the file is created fine :)
Code:

```
import sys
import time
Version = "V0.1"
def user():
    PISBNdat = open("PISBN.dat", "w")
    PISBNdat.write(Version)
    cuser = raw_input("Please enter account username!")
    for line in PISBNdat:
        print "Test"
        if cuser in line:
            print("User already exists! Try again!")
            user()



def start():
    print "Hello and welcome to Plaz's PISBN!"
    print "Opening file..."
    time.sleep(0.8)
    try:
        fin = open("PISBN.dat", "r")
        print "Success!"
        fin.close()
        user()
    except:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Did not recognize/find file!"
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Creating file!"
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            fout = open("PISBN.dat", "w")
            print "Success!"
            fout.close()
            user()
        except:
            print "Failed!"
            exit()

start()
```

And here's the output...:

```
Hello and welcome to Plaz's PISBN!
Opening file...
Did not recognize/find file!
Creating file!
Success!
Please enter account username! [This is what I entered: Plazmotech]
Failed!
```

Now obviously, since it said 'Failed!', it means its running my try block... because thats the only place it could output 'Failed!' So please help here!

Comment: you shouldn't use a bare `except:`, you should except the exception which you expect, eg `except IOError:` I believe, in this case.

Comment: Your `try...except` blocks should contain the minimal amount of code necessary to catch an error. Your first `try` block, for example should _only_ contain the line `fin = open("PISBN.dat", "r")` and your except block should merely create the file. `user()` should be called outside of both blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Catch only the exceptions you want to handle. Note that printing "Failed!" and exiting is *not* handling an exception. Python's going to do that anyway, plus it's going to give you a buttload of information as to what happened, so why write extra code that does less and hides the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As somebody (who just deleted his post) pointed out before, you call user() again in your user function, which is likely by mistake here.

I however believe your problems lie somewhere else. I assume you want "PISBN.dat" to contain a database where you look up for accounts. However, opening the file with only write permission will not help there. This causes your loop "for line in PISBNdat:" not working at all, so that the message "Test" did not appear.

It makes me think that "raw_input" failed and exception is caught. But as kindall pointed out, your code has some design flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `start()` with correct `try...except` usage:

```
def start():
    print "Hello and welcome to Plaz's PISBN!"
    print "Opening file..."
    time.sleep(0.8)
    try: #try bloc contains minimum amount of code to catch the pertinent error.
        f = open("PISBN.dat", "r")
        print "Success!"
    except IOError: #Only catch the exceptions you want to handle. IOError, in this case
        f = None

    if not f:
        print "Did not recognize/find file!"
        print "Creating file!"

        try:
            f = open("PISBN.dat", "w")
            print "Success!"
        except IOError:
            print "Failed!"
            exit()

    f.close()
    user() #Call user() after the file has been tested and/or created.
```